# CrystalReportsViewer Debug Error Message

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I incorporate CrystalReportsViewer in my WPF app using VS 2015. Here is my View:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KnoxFactoryLoader.Views"
    xmlns:Viewer="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer" ToolTip="Production Batch Report" x:Name="ProductionBatch" x:Class="KnoxFactoryLoader.Views.Report_View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"    
    Title="Production Batch Report View" Height="600" Width="700">
    <Viewer:CrystalReportsViewer Name="rptView" ShowLogo="False" ShowToolbar="True" ShowToggleSidePanelButton="False"
       ToggleSidePanel="None" Focusable="True" ShowOpenFileButton="False" 
                                 ShowCopyButton="False"  ShowRefreshButton="False" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   </Window>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
public partial class Report_View : Window
{
    public Report_View(string param1, string reportName)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument reportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
        reportDocument.Load(reportName);
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables CrTables;
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo();
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName1";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName1";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "user1";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "pass1";

        CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo2 = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo();
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo2 = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo2.ServerName = "ServerName2";
        crConnectionInfo2.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName2";
        crConnectionInfo2.UserID = "user2";
        crConnectionInfo2.Password = "pass2";

        CrTables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            if (CrTable.Name.Equals("TABLE1"))
            {
                crtableLogoninfo2 = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo2.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo2;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo2);
            }
            else
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }
        }
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("Param1", param1);
        InitializeComponent();
        rptView.ViewerCore.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        var viewer = rptView as SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer;
        if (viewer != null)
        {
            viewer.Focusable = true;
            viewer.Focus();
        }
    }
```

The report created is correct. However, there are a lot of debug error messages.

System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnOpen'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnOpen'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnPrint'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnPrint'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnRefresh'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnRefresh'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnExport'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnExport'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnCopy'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnCopy'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='ToggleButton' (Name='btnToggleSidePanel'); target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name='btnToggleSidePanel'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnPrevPage'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnPrevPage'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnNextPage'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnNextPage'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')

I search SAP website and couldn't find a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known problem with Crystal Report Viewer and WPF. You can add following code to avoid this error:

```
public partial class Report_View : Window
{
    public Report_View(string param1, string reportName)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument reportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
        reportDocument.Load(reportName);
        ...
```

More info you can find [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3722813).

Comment: Then make this as answered to @kmatyaszek